# Performance testing of Thick client

Tags: client-server, jmeter, performance-testing, jnlp, loadrunner

I have a thick client application to be tested. We need to downlod the jnlp file and then launch it, supply required credentials and click submit. It then launches the application.

I'm newbie to performance testing and want to performance test this application. Which open source tool will be useful, which is the best tool for testing thick clients?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "Performance testing of Thick client"? If it is about how fast it launches, downloads or operates than you need to loop into desktop automation software. The best open source tools currently available for desktop testing automation are:

- [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)
- [LDTP](http://ldtp.freedesktop.org/wiki/)

If your application does network communication and your scenario assumes simulating hundreds or thousands of simultaneous thick clients communicating with the server using the following open-source tools can help:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Gatling](http://gatling.io/)
- [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)

If your application supports proxy (given .jnlp - it is Java-based application and it [surely does](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html)) and the protocol is HTTP(S) you will be able to record test scenario and replay. The `Grinder` tool recording proxy can go a lower level and perform TCP protocol recording.

For more information on main features comparison for performance testing tools listed above look into [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) post.

If your application uses a form of secure communication or proprietary protocol you should be able to replicate it's behavior by plugging your application libraries to JMeter, Grinder or Gatling and use their multithreading and reporting features to perform massive load testing.

Comment: thx for the reply, i want to performance test application by sending many simultaneous client and then checking server performance.