# Performance testing on jnlp application

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jnlp, ubikloadpack

We have a web application from where we launch a jnlp application. This jnlp application is developed in Java and is used for image viewing. This application interacts with server.

We need to do a performance testing of this application. I tried with JMeter, it records properly the actions of web application but unable to record anything for jnlp application.

Has someone done the performance testing of jnlp application using Jmeter ? If Jmeter does not support it, is there any other tool which I can use to do the performance testing on it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the sourcecode or know how to use the code on jar level ? Then you can use jmeter to call the code in a load test, but you have to code it: as far as I know you can't record those calls. This may have some alternatives for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801068/performance-testing-of-thick-client

Comment: I already checked those tools and none of them is able to record the jnlp application.

Comment: But they should be able to "automate" your application for you. A quick search for webstart performance test record returned this: https://community.microfocus.com/borland/test/silk_performer_-_application_performance_testing/f/30/t/10423.aspx

Answer (score 0):

See this answer on how to record with JMeter:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/49569079/460802
- [How to record a JNLP/ Java Web Start application with JMeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566143/how-to-record-a-jnlp-java-web-start-application-with-jmeter)

Then you will need a plugin that transforms your Requests/Responses (binary) to a readable (XML) format so that you can variabilize, asserts ... ie , make the test realistic:

- https://www.ubik-ingenierie.com/blog/load-testing-java-serialization-applications-with-jmeter/

You'll need this JMeter plugin:

- [JavaSerialization plugin for JMeter](https://ubikloadpack.com/)

**Disclaimer:**

- We develop this **commercial** (not free) plugin.